# How to write C++ on Mac?

Tags: c++, ios, macos

Taking my first C++ class in college. I need to download C++ and my teacher gave us a direct link to download it, but it only works on Windows. Is there a way I can format it to work on my Mac or is there a Mac-friendly version I can download?

Comment: I usually get GCC and Clang from macports.org. They have builds for the latest released versions.

Comment: When you say "download C++", do you mean something like Visual Studio Express?  Or mingw?  There are lots of "C++"'s out there, and the one you need for your class may unfortunately matter when it comes to being graded.  You want to build and test your work on the compiler most similar to the one you'll be graded on.

Comment: Download Xcode from the Mac Store for free.  You can develop in C, C++ and Objective-C (https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12).

Comment: @RoboticCat and you can point it to, say, a Python executable too in build/scheme settings to write Python. Assume the technique works for other languages, I've only used it for C/C++ and Python.

Answer (score 7):

A compiler for C++ is already built into Mac (try `g++ main.cpp` in terminal). If you mean an IDE for C++, use [Xcode 5](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), available in app store.

It's developed by Apple, has git integration too if that's useful to you. Also has templates and such available to entice you to work on OS X/iOS projects, which might be a nice way in for you (I'm just starting out too, and I think that could be good).

For command-line projects though, I find it best to write in Xcode, then compile and run from the terminal. It's easier for file I/O and passing arguments to stdin IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize something called Xcode IDE to write your programs on C++, I have been using that for a quite a while now, and it's definitely fun. You can find the app from free on APP store or just by clicking the link below. This is one of the many things I like about MAC.

[click here to get XCODE](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, since you are just starting out, use XCode. Its a pretty neat IDE with built in C++ compiler so you can write C++, compile with a click and run.

Answer (score 1):

I think you kinda have the wrong idea of c++.
C++ is a programming language and what you are asking about is a development environment.
For example Xcode is such an environment. Since I also have my favorite I would use Eclipse since it is useful for many other purposes too.

[Eclipse C++ Download](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/keplersr1)